# Gridview item based on its height in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using `GridView` to display products. Now, issue is that items overlap on each other if any item contains large height image or if it contains long title. How do I prevent this ? I need help to display products same as like below screen shot. How can I do this ?

[image: Products]

Comment: @PradeepGupta, It is simple `Gridview` which we use in android.

Comment: @JeetenParmar show us your xml of the images, not the grid view

Comment: @JeetenParmar you can take the fix size for image in your xml or you can resize the images at run time.

Comment: @PradeepGupta, Mostly Image size is same but title text differs and that's why some items overlap.